# How to dynamically create button for calling specific action using map array in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried to map an array in **react** and tried to generate a button that will perform a specific action ,that is referencing another `object` generated by the same array using `map()` function.I'm using material-ui to speed up my development process.

I am very new to react (actually this is my first project with react), so maybe this is just simple question to implement 'state' in react, but i'm a little bit confusing to use `this` and `bind` syntax properly.

P.S -So excuse me for my stupidity :>

Follow this [link](http://%20https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-91eqw?fontsize=14) to reproduce the code

and this is the code i got trouble with:

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/676/676434.png",
    title: "Pineaple",
    price: "Rp. 14.000",
    desc: "Pineaple is one of nutritious food"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/676/676433.png",
    title: "Banana",
    price: "Rp. 14.000",
    desc: "Banana is one of nutritious food"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/676/676441.png",
    title: "Dragonfruit",
    price: "Rp. 14.000",
    desc: "Dragonfruit is one of nutritious food"
  },
];


export default function Posts(props) {

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  function handleClickOpen() {
    setOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container spacing={1} justify="center">

        {products.map(product => (
          <Grid item xs={6} sm={3} md={2} key={product.id}>
            <Card>
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  width="auto"
                  height="auto"
                  image={product.img}
                />
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography component="h2"> {product.title} </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2" color="primary" component="p">
                    {" "}{product.price}{" "}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
              <CardActions>
                <Button onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                  Buy
                </Button>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>

      {products.map(product => (
        <Dialog
          key={product.id}
          fullScreen
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          <AppBar position="sticky">
            <Toolbar>
              <IconButton onClick={handleClose}>
                <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography> {product.title} </Typography>
              <Button onClick={handleClose}> buy </Button>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <List className={classes.dialogue}>
            <img src={product.img} alt={product.title} />
            <ListItem button>
              <ListItemText primary={product.title} secondary={product.desc}/>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Dialog>
      ))}

    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to make `onclick` button generated by **mapped array** to reference to specific action (show specific dialog within array list). I also want to implement same method for `onSubmit` on 'buy' button in the Dialog.

Screenshoot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Lps.jpg
(I click buy on 'pineaple' but react render all list and show the latest object in a the list which is 'dragonfruit'.)

I guess i'll use `redux` but maybe not right now.

Anyway that's it, I really appreciate any response and helps :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can solve this but I will show you one. You are making use of React Hooks and you have a hook for setting the open/close state. In my solution, I make slight modification by adding another hook to set the selected product and then checking if both open and the product are set.

```
export default function Posts(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [product, setProduct] = React.useState(null);

  function handleClickOpen(event, item) {
    event.persist();
    setProduct(item);
    setOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setOpen(false);
  }
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={1} justify="center">
        {products.map(product => (
          <Grid item xs={6} sm={3} md={2} key={product.id}>
            <Card elevation={0}>
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  width="auto"
                  height="auto"
                  image={product.img}
                />
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography component="h2"> {product.title} </Typography>
                  <Typography variant="body2" color="primary" component="p">
                    {' '}
                    {product.price}{' '}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
              <CardActions>
                <Button
                  variant={'outlined'}
                  size="small"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={event => handleClickOpen(event, product)}
                >
                  Buy
                </Button>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
      {open && product && (
        <Dialog
          key={product.id}
          className={classes.dialogue}
          fullScreen
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          BackdropProps={{ classes: { root: classes.root } }}
          PaperProps={{ classes: { root: classes.paper } }}
        >
          <AppBar position="sticky">
            <Toolbar>
              <IconButton
                edge="start"
                color="inherit"
                onClick={handleClose}
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                {product.title}
              </Typography>
              <Button color="inherit" onClick={handleClose}>
                buy
              </Button>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar>
          <List className={classes.dialogue}>
            <Image
              className={classes.images}
              src={product.img}
              alt={product.title}
            />
            <ListItem button>
              <ListItemText primary={product.title} secondary={product.desc} />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Dialog>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In your code, you didn't have a way to track the currently selected product hence you always get the last item in the loop. By using another hook for the selected product, I can track the selected product. I hope this helps you and good luck in your mastery of React.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. It's works!
I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Sure, it's done! I am newbie here, it gives me some time for just figure out where the button is, lol

Answer (score 0):

You are having two states open and close.

You are using map on array and showing the dialog box.

The dialog box will open when open state is true.
This will be true for all elements in the array. Dialog box will be shown for all elements.
Now, they will overlap on each other and you can only see the last one.
When you click on close dialog your open state set to false and all the dialogs are closed.

Hint :- 
Maintain a state that will contain the id of element for which dialog is to be shown. Show dialog only when id state matches with the element's id